# Running a function multiple times and storing values in a vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

This is a simple function to simulate a snakes and ladders board game. When I run the function it outputs a single value. I want to repeat this process n number of times and store the values in a vector.

I've tried `lapply(1:1000, snakesnl())` but get this error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])`

```
snakesnl <- function(){
i <- 1
s <- 0
while (i < 25){
  s <- s + 1
  d <- sample(1:6,1)
  i <- i + d
}
return(s)
}
```

How would I use a for loop to store the results in a vector? or even use the apply family of functions. Both methods would be good to know.

Comment: Try `replicate(1000,snakesnl())`

Comment: `lapply(1:1000, snakesnl)` in lapply you need to pas the function. if you function does not have an argument, you need to create lambda function: `lapply(1:1000, function(x) snakesnl())`

Comment: Great! Both answers work fine. If I was to include a for loop in the function itself, how would I go about implementing it?